# If rank$(AB)=0$, then rank$(B)\leq $nullity$(A)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Intuitively, this is true. But I'm unsure how to prove it. I know that rank$(AB)=0\Rightarrow AB=0$, but how do I use this to show that the rank of $B$ is at most the nullity of $A$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interpreting the matrices as linear maps, the rank of $B$ is the dimension of the image of $B$, and the nullity of $A$ is the dimension of the kernel of $A$. If $\operatorname{Im}B\subseteq \ker A$ (which is to say, the composition of the two maps is the zero map), then we must have the inequality you're asking for.

Comment: Can you clarify how this proves the statement? I understand that CS$(B)\subseteq$NS$(A)\Rightarrow$ rank$(B)\leq$ nullity$(A)$ (sorry, more comfortable with 'column space' and 'null space' than 'image' and 'kernel') but how does this play in to the hypothesis that the rank of the product is 0?

Comment: @Lithobatkis The product being the zero map (which you said yourself is equivalent to the rank of the product being zero) means _exactly_ that $CS(B)\subseteq NS(A)$.

Comment: Okay, I see what you meant by the composition of the two maps being the zero map. Now I just need to convince myself that $CS(B)\subseteq NS(A)$ is equivalent to rank$(AB)=0$.

Comment: @Lithobatkis If $AB=0$, then for any compatible vector $v$ (i.e. of the right dimension), we have $ABv=0$, which is to say $A(Bv)=0$, so $Bv\in NS(A)$.